# spark spark-ec2 credentials using aws_security_token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, boto, spark-ec2

I would like to ask if it is currently possible to use spark-ec2 script https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html together with credentials that are consisting not only from: `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`, but it also contains `aws_security_token`.

When I try to run the script I am getting following error message:

```
ERROR:boto:Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/zikes/opensource/spark/ec2/lib/boto-2.34.0/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 64] Host is down>
ERROR:boto:Unable to read instance data, giving up
No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['QuerySignatureV2AuthHandler'] Check your credentials
```

Does anyone has some idea what can be possibly wrong? Is `aws_security_token` the problem?
It maybe seems to me more as boto than Spark problem.

I have tried both:

1) setting credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`

2) setting credential by commands:

```
export aws_access_key_id=<my_aws_access_key>
export aws_secret_access_key=<my_aws_seecret_key>
export aws_security_token=<my_aws_security_token>
```

My launch command is:

```
./spark-ec2 -k my_key -i my_key.pem --additional-tags "mytag:tag1,mytag2:tag2" --instance-profile-name "profile1" -s 1 launch test
```

Comment: Check the error message. It says: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 64] Host is down>

Open spark-ec2 script and check the URL is valid and the host is up and running.

Comment: Actually there is no url in spark-ec2 script. 
And I don't even know from where is this called. There was also no machine created at all at my AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not use profile called `default` after renaming everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

you can setup your credentials & config using the command `aws configure`.
I had the same issue but in my case my AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY had a slash, I regenerated the key until there was no slash and it worked